# On  $\pi_1$ of an algebraic surface

Tags: complex-manifolds

I have the following question. Any input would be appreciated. If you have a counterexample, I would be very interested to know.

Question. Let $(X, \omega, J)$ be a Kahler manifold of complex dimension $2$ of general type, with $\omega$ a symplectic form and $J$ an integrable complex structure compatible with $\omega$. Let $L$ be an ample line bundle on $X$. Assume the divisor $D$ corresponding to $L$ is connected, symplectic curve with a positive self-intersection. Is there is a surjection $\pi_{1}(D) \rightarrow \pi_{1}(X)$?

Remark: Note that here I don't assume that the divisor $D$ is holomorphic. In this case the answer to my question is yes by Nori's result. I am asking if Nori's result holds for symplectic submanifold.

Comment: Could you please define what you mean by a pesudo-holomorphic curve in your case? In order to do this, you need to define an almost complex structure on your Kahler surface, but have not explained this. Note also, that any Kahler manifold with an ample bundle is projective thanks to Kodaira embedding theorem.

Comment: Dmitri@ I consider a compatiable almost-complex structure $J$ on $(X, \omega)$, where $\omega$ is a Kahler form. The submanifold $D$ of $X$ is a pseudo-holomorphic if $J$ maps the tangent bundle of $D$ into itself. In my question above, you can assume $D$ is a symplectic submanifold of $X$. I consider the symplectic structure given by the Kahler form.

Comment: Dear kla:  Could you please give a reference to an article or book that defines "Kaehler form" for a manifold which is not a complex manifold?  I am concerned that you are misunderstanding the term "Kaehler form".

Comment: Dear Jason: In my question above, I assume that the manifold $X$ is a complex surface of general type.

Comment: @kla: "Dear Jason: In my question above, I assume that the manifold X is a complex surface of general type."  In that case, what is your distinction between "pseudo-holomorphic" and "holomorphic"?  A pseudo-holomorphic curve in a <complex> manifold is holomorphic.  Once again, I think you should tell us what reference you are using, since you seem to be confused about basic definitions.

Comment: @Jason I am using the definition on page 389 of R. Gompf and A. Stipsicz "4-Manifolds and Kirby calculus". It defines pseudo-holomorphic submanifold on the almost-complex 4-manifold $X$ as a real 2-dimensional submanifold $\Sigma$ such that if $J$ maps the tangent bundle of $\Sigma$ into itself. If you look the same page, it remarks that if $X(\omega, J, g)$ is an almost-Kahler manifold then a pseudo-holomorphic submanifold $\Sigma$ is alwyas a symplectic submanifold. I didn't know that pseudo-holomorphic should be holomorphic as you remark (in Kahler case). 

Comment: @kla: Since your almost complex structure is assumed to be integrable, your pseudoholomorphic curve is a complex curve. Hence, you are done by Nori's theorem. 

Comment: I think the question is badly phrased. Maybe the OP asks if a connected symplectic surface $D$ in $X$ whch is Poincaré dual to $c_1(L)$ with ample $L$ and $c_1(L)^2>0$ still verifies Nori's theorem. Am I right ?

Comment: Yes, BS that is what exactly I am asking. THANK YOU! According to the page 389 of Gompf and Stipsicz an embedded surface $\Sigma$ is a symplectic submanifold if and only if there is a compatiable almost complex structure $J$ such that $\Sigma$ is pseudo-holomorphic. I know there are examples of Kahler surfaces such as $\mathbb{T} \times \mathbb{T}$ which contain a symplectic but non-complex connected curves. For example, there is a connected symplectic surface which represent the homology class $n(\mathbb{T} \times {pt})$ (for any $n \geq 2$), but there exist no such holomorphic curve. 

Comment: You should edit your question, then.

Comment: ... In particular, remove integrability assumption and Kahler assumption. I am also unsure what "general type" would mean in the setting suggested by BS. 

Comment: Is the line bundle a holomorphic line bundle?

Comment: ... At least, replace Kahler with "almost Kahler". 

Comment: @Misha My question was about the symplectic submanifolds of Kahler surface. I think I made this very clear in my post. 

Comment: kla: Do I understand right that the question is as follows? Let $X$ be an algebraic surface of general type, and $\omega$ a Kaehler form in class $K_X$. Suppose that $D$ is a connected, oriented surface embedded in $X$ such that $\omega|_D>0$. Assume that the homology class $[D]$ is Poincare dual to $c_1(L)$, where $L$ is an ample holomorphic line bundle (so in particular, ($D \cdot D > 0$). Must $D$ then carry all of $\pi_1(X)$?

Comment: @Tim Yes, this is exactly my question!  